# quantiles of a monotonic function of two independent R.V.s

Tags: probability, random-variables, quantile

Consider two independent random Variables $X, Y$, and $X>=0, Y>=0$. $f(X, Y)$ is monotonic to $X, Y$ respectively.

Suppose that we know the 0%, 25%, 50%, 75%, 100% quantiles for both $X, Y$ and we have access to $f(\cdot, \cdot)$.

Is it possible to find some quantiles of the new R.V. $Z = f(X, Y)$?

Quantile is invariant to monotonic transformation but is there any nice property when we consider the scenario above?

I appreciate a lot for any hint. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you know  $100\%$ quantiles, i.e. you know $c$ and $d$ such that $X \le c$ and $Y \le d$ with probability $1$, then $Z = f(X,Y) \le f(c,d)$ with probability $1$. This says $f(c,d)$ is a $100\%$ quantile for $Z$.  (I say **a** rather than **the**, because in general quantiles are not unique).

Similarly for $0\%$.

Not for any of the others, though: they would require knowing the actual distributions, at least in some interval.

Comment: Hi, Robert, thanks a lot for your answer. Yes 0% and 100% quantiles are something we could find. And I had a feeling it just requires more information to find quantiles between. But if we know the actual distributions, we know the distribution of $Z$. Instead of knowing its distribution, I am more interested in characterizing the distribution of $Z$ by its quantiles, (i.e., building connection between $Q^X_i, Q^Y_j$ and some $Q^Z$) . I might be able to add some information but I'd like to avoid adding too much. Could you elaborate a bit about if we know distributions in some intervals? thx :)